# sveltekit: Module '"$app/stores"' has no exported member 'session'

Tags: session, sveltekit

I am trying to migrate a sveltekit app from older versions to the latest. session has been removed from $app/stores.

I have not been able to find references to new session in the current documentation.

I use this reference in +layout.svelte

```
    <script lang="ts">
        import { session } from '$app/stores';
    </script>
```

and also call GetSession from hooks.ts:

```
    import type { GetSession, Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';
```

What is the new way of referencing them?

Ben.

Comment: I don't think there's a "best" way, and mostly depends on your use case. I find myself mostly using `session` in actual *.svelte files, rather than in hooks, but I'm sure there's someone who disagrees.

Comment: Did you get the answer you were looking for elsewhere?

Comment: Could you share some more code illustrating how you used session?

Answer (score 0):

The session was removed some time ago: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5883

Instead of a session you should use `$page.data`:

```
<script>
  import { page } from '$app/stores';
</script>
```